# How can I connect two signal to a block?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My code is:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle,minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em]
    \tikzstyle{block2} = [draw, fill=white!20, rectangle,minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em]
    \tikzstyle{block3} = [draw, fill=green!20, rectangle,minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em]
    \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white!20, circle, node distance=1.5cm]
    \tikzstyle{sum1} = [draw, fill=white!20, circle, node distance=1.5cm]
    \tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
    \tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
    \tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,white}]


    % The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=3.0cm,>=latex']


    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [input, name=input]{};
    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum){$\Sigma$};
    \node [block, right of=sum,pin={[pinstyle]below:\scriptsize Controlador PI 1}, node distance = 2.5cm](controlador1){$K_{pv}+\frac{K_{iv}}{s}$};

    \node [sum1, right of=controlador1,node distance = 2.5cm] (sum1){$\Sigma$};

    \node [block, right of=controlador1,pin={[pinstyle]below:\scriptsize Controlador PI 2}, node distance = 5cm](controlador2){$K_{pi}+\frac{K_{ii}}{s}$};

    \node [block2, right of=controlador2,pin={[pinstyle]below:\scriptsize Planta de Corrente}, node distance = 3cm](planta1){$G_i(s)$};

    \node [block2, right of=planta1,pin={[pinstyle]below:\scriptsize Planta de Tensão}, node distance = 3cm](planta2){$G_v(s)$};



    % calculate the coordinate vpwm. We need it to place the ems block.
    \draw [->] (controlador2) -- node[name=vpwm] {$d$} (planta1);
    \node [output, right of=planta2,node distance=2.8cm] (output) {};
    \node [block3, below of=sum1,pin={[pinstyle]below:\scriptsize }] (ems) {$Energy\ Management\ System$};


    %connect the nodes
    \draw [draw, ->](input) -- node {$V_{ref}$}(sum);
    \path [->] (sum) edge node {$V_{err}$} (controlador1);
    \path [->] (controlador1) edge node {$I^*_{batt}$}(sum1);
    \path [->] (sum1) edge node {$I_{err}$}(controlador2);
    \path [->] (controlador2) edge node {}(planta1);
    \path [->] (planta1)edge node {$I_{bat}$}(planta2) node[pos=0.95]{$+$};
    \path [->] (planta2) edge node [name=theta] {$V_{DC}$}(output);
    \draw [->] (theta) |- (ems);
    \draw [->] (ems) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$}
    node [near end] {$V_{med}$} (sum);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result I desire is:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Torbjørn T. and Alan Munn gave you soooo nice answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438581/121799) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438582/121799), and you are using `\tikzstyle` again?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The vertical arrow you know how to do, that's just drawing a line from `ems` to `sum1` with a couple of nodes. Nothing new.

For the other, you can give the `I_{batt}` node a name (I used `ibatt`), and then use

```
\draw [->] (ibatt) |- (ems.5);
```

to draw the arrow. You know the `|-` syntax, the `.5` indicates an angle of 5 degrees, so you get the point that is on the border of the node, at an angle of 5. If you similarly use `\draw [->] (theta) |- (ems.355);` to draw the other arrow to `ems`, the two arrows will be equally distant from the `east` anchor of `ems`.

One other point (in addition to the same things as your previous question): Don't write `$Energy\ Management\ System$`. That's text, not math, so don't write it in math mode. Use just `Energy Management System`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\tikzset{
  block/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle,minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em},
  block2/.style={draw, fill=white!20, rectangle,minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em},
  block3/.style={draw, fill=green!20, rectangle,minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em},
  sum/.style={draw, fill=white!20, circle, node distance=1.5cm},
  sum1/.style={draw, fill=white!20, circle, node distance=1.5cm},
  input/.style={coordinate},
  output/.style={coordinate},
  pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,white}}
}

\begin{document}



    % The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=1.5cm,>=latex']


    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [input, name=input]{};
    \node [sum, right=of input] (sum){$\Sigma$};
    \node [block, right=of sum,pin={[pinstyle]below:\scriptsize Controlador PI 1}](controlador1){$K_{pv}+\frac{K_{iv}}{s}$};

    \node [sum1, right=of controlador1] (sum1){$\Sigma$};

    \node [block, right=4cm of controlador1,pin={[pinstyle]below:\scriptsize Controlador PI 2}](controlador2){$K_{pi}+\frac{K_{ii}}{s}$};

    \node [block2, right=of controlador2,pin={[pinstyle]below:\scriptsize Planta de Corrente},](planta1){$G_i(s)$};

    \node [block2, right=of planta1,pin={[pinstyle]below:\scriptsize Planta de Tensão}](planta2){$G_v(s)$};



    % calculate the coordinate vpwm. We need it to place the ems block.
    \draw [->] (controlador2) -- node[name=vpwm] {$d$} (planta1);
    \node [output, right=of planta2,node distance=2.8cm] (output) {};
    \node [block3, below=of sum1,pin={[pinstyle]below:\scriptsize }] (ems) {Energy Management System};


    %connect the nodes

    \draw [->] (ems) -- (sum1) node[pos=0.8,swap] {$I_{\mathrm{foo}}$} node[swap,pos=0.99] {$-$};

    \draw [->](input) -- node {$V_{\mathrm{ref}}$}(sum);
    \path [->] (sum) edge node {$V_{\mathrm{err}}$} (controlador1);
    \path [->] (controlador1) edge node {$I^*_{\mathrm{batt}}$}(sum1);
    \path [->] (sum1) edge node {$I_{\mathrm{err}}$}(controlador2);
    \path [->] (controlador2) edge node {}(planta1);
    \path [->] (planta1)edge node (ibatt) {$I_{\mathrm{batt}}$}(planta2) node[pos=0.95]{$+$}; % added (ibatt) name to first node
    \path [->] (planta2) edge node [name=theta] {$V_{DC}$}(output);
    \draw [->] (theta) |- (ems.355); % use a specific anchor -- 355 indicates an angle
    \draw [->] (ems) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$}  node [near end] {$V_{\mathrm{med}}$} (sum);

    \draw [->] (ibatt) |- (ems.5); % above we used 355, so here we use 5, which makes it symmetric
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but is not centralized, how to make the two arrows stay centralized in the "Energy Management System"?

Comment: Instead of a manual adjustment, I would use the angular border anchors. This would allow you to put the incoming lines equally spaced: use `(ems.355)` and `(ems.5)`  for the bottom and top lines respectively.

Comment: @SrnLord You didn't say anything at about that in the question, and your drawing doesn't illustrate it. I can't read your mind, if you have specific demands, then you have to state  those clearly in the question. Alan's suggestion makes sense in that case, I'll edit in a bit.

Comment: @AlanMunn I went by the drawing, didn't think about any symmetry. But good idea, thanks.

Comment: Sorry Torbjorn,  I did not mean to sound rude

Comment: @SrnLord You didn't sound rude exactly (I probably sounded more rude), just remember to clearly explain what you want to do.

Comment: @SrnLord Is my updated answer what you wanted, by the way?

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, another option using nodes relating to shapes, for example for the arrows in the `EMS` (Energy management System) `EMS.4` and `EMS.-4`, node which is the node that intercepts the edge of the shape with the written angle (see `section 17.9` in [visual tikz](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf) manual).

To name all the arrows I use the definitions of nodes in paths, which allows you to find and define a node at a certain distance according to a factor, you can see them in the visual tikz manual `section 7.9`.

The `mixer node` is given by `circuitikz` package, and the insertion of the signs is done by labels relative to nodes `section 7.7 in` the manual.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% By J. Leon V. Share as Beerware philosophy
\documentclass[tikz, border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsbsy}% Used to make bold text in math mode by macro \pmb
%\usepackage{xcolor}% This package is already loaded by tikz (Obs. thanks to: Torbjørn T)
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}% Used for mixer node.
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows.meta,%increase options for arrows personalization
    shapes, % include nodes relative to the shape.
    positioning % Allows positioning relative to nodes.
    } 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment Configuration
        %None global cfg
        %Styles
        Block/.style = {% Style for block systems
            rectangle, 
            draw,
            minimum height=3em, 
        },
        Sign/.style = {% Style for signs in mixer 
            font=\tiny,
            label distance=-1.5pt
        },
        Name/.style = {% Style for arrow labels
            font=\small,
            label distance=5pt
        },
        MyArrow/.style = {% Style for arrows
            line width=0.75pt,
            -{Stealth[inset=0pt]}, % It causes tokenExeptions in TikzEdt, but compiles normally.
        },
    ]
    % Start drawing "the thing..." 
    \node (Input)[%Initial node
    ]{};
    \node (Sum1)[%first Mixer
        mixer, % From Circuitikz
        scale=0.6,
        right=1.2cm of Input, % Position declaration for positioning lib.
        label={[Sign]180:$\pmb{+}$},
        label={[Sign]-90:$\pmb{-}$},
    ]{};
    \node(PI-1)[%First block system
        Block,
        right=1.5cm of Sum1,
        fill=blue!30,
        label={[Name]-90:Controlador PI 1},
    ]{$K_{pv}+\frac{K_{iv}}{s}$};
    \node (Sum2)[%Second mixer
        mixer, % From Circuitikz
        scale=0.6,
        right=1.2cm of PI-1, % Position declaration for positioning lib.
        label={[Sign]180:$\pmb{+}$},
        label={[Sign]-90:$\pmb{-}$},
    ]{};
    \node(PI-2)[%Second block system
        Block,
        right=1.5cm of Sum2,
        fill=blue!30,
        label={[Name]-90:Controlador PI 2},
    ]{$K_{pi}+\frac{K_{ii}}{s}$};
    \node(Gi)[
        Block,
        right=1.5cm of PI-2,
        %fill=blue!30,
        minimum width=1.5cm,
        label={[Name]-90:Planta de corriente},
    ]{$G_i(S)$};
    \node(Gv)[
        Block,
        right=2.5cm of Gi,
        %fill=blue!30,
        minimum width=1.5cm,
        label={[Name]-90:Planta de Tensão},
    ]{$G_v(s)$};
    \node (Output)[
        right=2.5cm of Gv,
    ]{};
    \node (EMS)[
        Block,
        inner xsep=5pt,
        fill=green!20,
        below=2cm of Sum2,
        minimum height=2.5em
    ]{\it Energy Management System};

    \draw[MyArrow] (Input) -- (Sum1.west) node[midway,above]{$V_{ref}$};
    \draw[MyArrow] (Sum1.east) -- (PI-1) node[midway,above]{$V_{err}$};
    \draw[MyArrow] (PI-1) -- (Sum2.west) node[midway,above]{$V^*_{batt}$};
    \draw[MyArrow] (Sum2.east) -- (PI-2) node[midway,above]{$I_{err}$};
    \draw[MyArrow] (PI-2) -- (Gi) node[midway,above]{$d$};
    \draw[MyArrow] (Gi) -- (Gv) node[ sloped,midway,](loop2){} node[midway,above]{$I_{bat}$};
    \draw[MyArrow] (Gv) -- (Output) node[sloped,midway](loop1){} node[midway,above]{$V_{DC}$};

    \draw[fill](loop1.center) circle (1.5pt); 
    \draw[MyArrow] (loop1.center) |- (EMS.-4); 
    \draw[fill](loop2.center) circle (1.5pt); 
    \draw[MyArrow] (loop2.center) |- (EMS.4);
    \draw[MyArrow] (EMS) -- (Sum2.south) node[midway, anchor=west]{$I_{med}$};
    \draw[MyArrow] (EMS) -| (Sum1.south) node[pos=0.77, anchor=east]{$V_{med}$};

     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Minor detail: `xcolor` (which by the way is already loaded by TikZ) *is* used, in for example `blue!30`. The `!` syntax is from `xcolor`.

Comment: Just for that reason I thought it was a default syntax, I'll clarify that topic.

Comment: one m0re minor detail: with option `tikz` document class `standalone, load the package `tikz`. therefore `\usepackage{tikz}` is not needed (but it will not harm).

Comment: Those minimal details are really important, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

an alternative way how to draw this block scheme:

[image]

in code are used library `chains` for positioning of nodes, `calc` for calculate coordinates of branch point and `quotes` for edge labels. defined is one rectangle node type which color is defined locally. for block labels are used `label and its sintax:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}

\tikzset{
     block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=#1, minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em,
                     on chain},
   block/.default = white,
       sum/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=6mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                     node contents={\huge$+$},
                     on chain},
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    node distance = 1.5cm,
      start chain = going right,
every edge/.style = {draw, semithick, -Stealth},
every label/.append style = {label distance=1mm, font=\scriptsize}
                        ]
% We start by placing the blocks
\coordinate[label=$+$,on chain] (input);
\node (sum) [sum];
\node (controlador1) [block=blue!30, label=below:Controlador PI 1] {$K_{pv}+\frac{K_{iv}}{s}$};
\node (sum1) [sum];
\node (controlador2) [block=blue!30, label=below:Controlador PI 2] {$K_{pi}+\frac{K_{ii}}{s}$};
\node (planta1) [block, label=below:Planta de Corrente] {$G_i(s)$};
\node (planta2) [block, label=below:Planta de Tensão] {$G_v(s)$};
\coordinate[on chain2] (output);
% Energy Management System + additional coordinates
\node(ems)  [block=green!30, below=of sum1] {Energy Management System};
\coordinate[above=2mm of ems.east] (ems1);
\coordinate[below=2mm of ems.east] (ems2);
%connect the nodes
\path   (input)         edge ["$V_{\mathrm{ref}}$"]     (sum)
        (sum)           edge ["$V_{\mathrm{err}}$"]     (controlador1)
        (controlador1)  edge ["$I^*_{\mathrm{batt}}$"]  (sum1)
        (sum1)          edge ["$I_{\mathrm{err}}$"]     (controlador2)
        (controlador2)  edge                            (planta1)
        (planta1)       edge ["$I_{\mathrm{batt}}$"]    (planta2)
        (planta2)       edge ["$V_{DC}$"]               (output)
        (ems)           edge ["$I_{\mathrm{foo}}$"] node[pos=0.95] {$-$}     (sum1);
%
    \begin{scope}[semithick, -Stealth]
\draw   (ems) -| node [near end] {$V_{\mathrm{med}}$} node[pos=0.95] {$-$}  (sum);
%
\draw   ($(planta2)!0.5!(planta1)$) |- (ems1);
\draw   ($(planta2.east)!0.5!(output)$) |- (ems2);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```